# File data is empty after uploading a PDF with Ionic File Chooser, PDF corrupted

Tags: angular, file, pdf, ionic-framework, base64

I'm using the plug-in `Chooser` from `@ionic-native/chooser/ngx` : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/chooser
My aim is to get a PDF file from my Downloads on my phone, and send it to a server in `base64`. But my server is getting a corrupted PDF.

I'm using it like this :

```
  openFiles() {
this.chooser
  .getFile('application/pdf')
  .then((file) => {
    console.log('L-119 --> File  : ' + JSON.stringify(file));}
```

But when I read the file in my console, I'm getting this :

[image]

**My data is empty !** **So I can't do anything with this, or maybe I'm missing something?**

For example, for a photo, i'm using the camera plugin, like this :

```
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
  (imageData) => {
    console.log('file ' + JSON.stringify(imageData));
```

And I'm getting this for result :

[image]

**My server gets a correct file and can open it**. Do you know how could I use these informations from the `chooser` plugin of Ionic, to send my PDF correctly?

**I would like to do it with the Ionic way.**

**EDIT 1 :**

Using Base64 plugin from Ionic

```
        const filePath = file.uri;
    this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then(
      (base64File: string) => {
        console.log('my base 64 file is ' + base64File);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

Result :
[image]

My base64 file from `Base64` Plugin is still empty.

**EDIT 2 :**

For Base64, we need to give the path of the file, not the URI. To get the path, I used `Ionic File Path` like this :

```
      this.filePath
      .resolveNativePath(file.uri)
      .then((resultat) => console.log('file path ' + resultat))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I receive this : `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy.pdf'`
And then with @Najam Us Saqib answer, I use `Ionic Base64` with that path, and I get this :

[image]

Problem solved now !

Comment: I think you are getting FILE URI not base64. Use this Plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64 to convert your File into base54 and send it to server. Also Add `console.log('L-119 --> File  : ' + JSON.stringify(file))` in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I get my file on my device before converting it, and using Ionic? Is there a way? Because here i can't even get the file, and work on it. As you said, it seems to give only the uri of the file, not its content

Comment: you don't need to get content. Just pass your File URI to base64 Plugin and it will convert it automatically and give you base64.

Comment: After doing this using the uri, i still get an empty thing. Check at my edit.

Comment: whats in your `file.uri` console and Check

Comment: Ok you're a genius man. For Base64 plugin, we have to set the file path, not the uri. So I used ```Ionic FilePath``` plugin, to get the path using the URI. Then, if I do the Base64 method for the right path, I get my file in base64. That is completely awesome, I spent days on it. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you post your answer, for me to vote it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `base64` Plugin [Base64](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64) to convert your File into base64 and send it to server.
Pass your FilePath to that plugin and it will convert your file into base64.
P.S: I recommend you to upload file as it is don't Use base64. it will enhance your Applications performance.

```
import { Base64 } from '@ionic-native/base64/ngx';

constructor(private base64: Base64) { }

...

let filePath: string = 'file:///...';
this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then((base64File: string) => {
  console.log(base64File);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```